# how to code for config files in android?

Tags: android, configuration-files, android-webservice

My aim is to call remote web services of a web application in order to invoke them in my android application. But i am unable to prepare config files such as verifying login credentials, getting authentication ticket & so on. Can anyone provide some hint or any idea or sample tutorial to do so. Any helpfull effort should be appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

Create an XML file in your res/values forlder (for example config.xml or etc) and declare your configs there , then access them from your java code :)
See this link for more info :
[developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html)

Comment: Can u post some code snippet. I think this can be done programmatically using some Getters Setters files & some credentials files according to the customized code written in web services.